Setting text-decoration-line to blink Doesn't Do Anything in Blazor
I'm trying to make text blink so as to draw the user's eye to it, but the text-decoration-line doesn't do anything when set to blink, despite all other variables applying correctly.
I found this question that says IE doesn't support it, so do no Microsoft products support it at all? Should I try and invest time in making a css animation instead?
HTML Code:
<p class="loading-text">@LoadingMessage</p>

CSS Class:
.loading-text {
    margin-bottom: 6px;
    text-decoration-line: blink;
    color: #26b050;
    text-decoration-style: double;
    position: center;
    text-align: center;
}

(The color was randomly picked so I could be confident the class was actually being applied correctly).

Oh wow. I don't have an answer to your question, but I don't think I've seen blink or marquee used since the late 90s early 2000s.

@Lex lol. I was just going off the auto-fill recommendations that Visual Studio was giving me.

blink has been deprecated and is obsolete and should not be used.

Personally, I'd just use a CSS animation like you were considering. There's tons of examples out there and you can do more eye catching things like pulsing the background color to draw attention.

Blink is deprecated, and most web browsers no longer support it.
If you are stumbling across this question because you are as unfamiliar with HTML as I am, Look up CSS animations like @Lex suggested.
